# RethinkDB import error

Tags: rethinkdb

I'm trying to import CSV or JSON file to Rethink DB but I always get the same error:

```
rethinkdb import -f ~/Downloads/convertcsv.json --table test.stats --format json
[                                        ]   0% 
0 rows imported in 1 table
'indexes'
In file: /home/xxxxx/Downloads/convertcsv.json
Errors occurred during import
```

I don't see anything in logs and the same files import ok on my laptop.
Import creates the table but that's about it.

My system:
 - List item
 - Ubuntu 10.10
 - Python 2.7.8
 - rethinkdb 1.16.0+1~0utopic (GCC 4.9.1)

Already tried to re-install RethinkDB, `sudo pip2 install --upgrade rethinkdb`. Not sure what else I can do.

Comment: Could you try with the `--no-secondary-indexes` flag?  If that doesn't work, it could be useful to see the output with the `--debug` flag.  This looks like an oversight when adding secondary index export/import.

Comment: I opened Github issue [#3278](https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/issues/3728) for this and fixed it.  There should be a new python driver release soon so no one else runs into this.  Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: --no-secondary-indexes helped. Can you please make your comment an answer so I can approve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to have been an oversight when adding export/import of secondary indexes - the import script is looking for the `indexes` field in the info, which doesn't exist when importing a single file.  This can be worked around by providing the flag `--no-secondary-indexes`.  A fix was released in the RethinkDB Python driver version `1.16.0-2`, see the Github issue [#3278](https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/issues/3728) for details.